# Filter HTML Table using JavaScript - textContent Error

Tags: javascript, php, html

**Desired Result:** Input data from a .csv file into PHP. Take the data from the .csv file and store into an array. Store the array into an HTML table using PHP. Use a search engine to filter through the rows using JavaScript.

I am getting the following error in the JavaScript:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null*

```
<script>  
const searchInput = document.getElementById("search");
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
//console.log(rows);

searchInput.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) { 
    //console.log(event);
    const q = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
       rows.forEach(row => {
          //console.log(row);
        row.querySelector("td").textContent.toLowerCase().startsWith(q); 
        ? (row.style.display = "table-row")
        : (row.style.display = "none");
    } );
});
 </script>
```

Using the console.log, I have been able to determine it is reading and looping through each row in the table correctly, but it is unable to loop through the 'td' to determine if it matches text in the search engine.

The Array is a NodeList when consoling out the rows if that information is useful.

Happy to upload more information if needed. Thank you for your help in advance!

**EDIT**
Adding in  minimal HTML. The table contains 15 rows, but for the purposes of this, only adding in a few. This table is creating from an array using PHP.

**EDIT 2** Headers added into thead

```
<html>
<head>  
</head> 
    <body>   
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search for services..">
    <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Make</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td><td>Cut &amp; Blow Dry</td>
    <td>Service</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Hair by Cass</td>
    <td>Haircut and style after</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `row.querySelector("td")` will only get you the first TD element of a row. Could you please provide the minimal HTML sample table with the search box?

Comment: Your HTML is not that valid. `<th>` should go in `<thead>` not in `<tbody>`

Comment: You first row does not contain any `td` that is the reason you are getting that error

Comment: I am testing out your code right now as well. I just adjusted my PHP loops to have the <th> in the <thead>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your HTML table markup is not correct. The row with the `<th>`s should go in `<thead>` not in `<tbody>`
- You're using invalid ternary operator syntax `; ? x : y`.
- Use rather the `"input"` event to account for mouse copy/paste stuff etc.

```js
searchInput.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
  const q = evt.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase();
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const matches = row.querySelector("td").textContent.toLowerCase().startsWith(q);
    row.style.display = matches ? "table-row" : "none";
  });
});
```

But keep in mind that `row.querySelector("td")` will only get the first TD in a row (not all of them):

#### Match for multiple cells using [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Here's an example that will allow you to search throughout any cell, and uses a better solution for the toggling by using [Element.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) (and `.includes()` instead of `.startsWith()`)

```js
const EL_search = document.querySelector("#search");
const ELS_rows = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

EL_search.addEventListener("input", function(evt) {
  const q = evt.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase();
  ELS_rows.forEach(TR => {
    const TDS = TR.querySelectorAll("td");
    const matches = [...TDS].some(TD =>TD.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(q));
    TR.classList.toggle("none", !matches);
  });
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Ann</td><td>Doe</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jon</td><td>Doe</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jonas</td><td>Foe</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've inputted this, but for some reason it is not filtering in my code. I adjusted the <input type> search as well to include what you noted.  But it works flawlessly on here. 

Can you explain what the [...TDS] does? (Sorry complete newb here)

Comment: @casscode look at my HTML. I use the `<thead>` properly. Make sure to adjust on your end as well!

Comment: @casscode Since TDS is a NodeList - it has not by default the `Array.prototype.some()` method - therefore by using [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `...` I'm converting an array-like NodeList to Array.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for explaining! I got this to work. Really appreciate all your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `row.querySelector("td")` because it's trying find `td` in the headers `tr` element which only contain `th` children.

The fix is simple, check if `td` was found before proceeding:

```
const td = row.querySelector("td");
if (!td)
  return;

td.textContent.toLowerCase().startsWith(q) ?
  (row.style.display = "table-row") :
  (row.style.display = "none");
```

Also, `querySelector` will only return first found element, if you need find all elements, use `querySelectorAll` which will return list of elements, and than use `for` loop to process all elements in the list.

```
const tds = row.querySelectorAll("td");

for(let i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
{
  tds[i].textContent.toLowerCase().startsWith(q) ?
    (row.style.display = "table-row") :
    (row.style.display = "none");
}
```

Comment: Look at their HTML, they have `tr` with only `th` children inside of `tbody`

Comment: @vanowm yes, I've seen the Q edit now. That's not the best HTML Table markup. OP is missing `<thead>`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, you are correct, they should fix the source instead of treating the symptoms...